# Show css comments in web inspector in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, comments, web-inspector

Is there a way to show the comments that are generated in my css file in websinspector, I can see the comments when I view the css file in the resources tab but I dont see them in the elements styles sidebar, is this possible, this would make my life super easy.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't think so. Where would they go? Comments are not attached to any particular style setting.

Comment: If you are the author of the css files and the comments in it then name your css classes and ID's like what they do, if you can. Then you also see it in every css inspector - this made my life super easy ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `/* ... */` comments, make up fake styles starting with `-`, e.g.

```
.foo {
  -my-comment1: Make all foos red;
  color: red;
}
```

These will show up in the inspector with a strike-through, since it doesn't recognize them.

Comment: @DavidThomas That describes most kludges.

Comment: if you start with double dashes like `--fordebug`  it will be understood by the browser as a variable and hence won't be crossed out or be disabled.